# Android NDK x86 and x86_64 ABI

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

I created recently a simple "Hello World" Android NDK project in Android Studio and tried to play with the gradle / cmake / clang build system.

I created a main.c file containing the main method:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world");
    return 0;
}
```

My cmakelist.txt file will compile this file using Android NDK toolchain to generate the executable that I named ndk_example_c:

```
add_executable( # Sets the name of the library.
        ndk_example_c

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        main.c
        )
```

gradle/cmake generates 4 binaries for the 4 default ABIs:

- armeabi-v7a
- arm64-v8a
- x86
- x86_64

I managed to run the arm abi executables on an Android device using adb shell. However, I expected to be able to run the x86 and x86_64 executables on Windows or Linux, but the binaries doesn't seem to be standard executables.

So, my question is: what is the target platform / OS of the x86 and x86_64 binaries generated by gradle? Did anyone manage to run them?

Thanks,

Comment: They're built for _Android_ x86/x86_64. Just like you can't take a Windows executable and run it on Linux (without some sort of emulation layer), you can't run an Android executable on Windows or Linux. They are different operating systems.

Comment: Actually, I thought Android was running in top of linux. This is why expected the program to run on Linux without additions.

Comment: It's based on a Linux kernel, but the kernel–userspace APIs aren't necessarily the same.

Comment: thanks, this explains the point. the filesystem hieararchy and configuration isn't quite the same, and I can see also that the default dynamic linker requested by the executable isn't the standard linux linker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most useful target platform for x86 or …64 is an Android emulator, which you can run via AVD without leaving Android Studio. There are other emulators, which may deliver better performance or additional features.

Another platform for these Android APKs is a ChromeBook. There is an independent [effort](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-x86-android-8-1-oreo/) to bring Android to any PC. Note that you may need some tuning for your app to look good on the big screen.

Finally, there exist some Android devices that feature Atom CPU. The phones like Asus ZenFone 2 are not very common these days, but you could find some STBs that use x86.

Comment: yes, I think the best way to run those is on android emulator for x86/x64 platforms or an intel device as you said. I can see when running the readelf command that the executables are looking for a dymanic loader located at /system/bin/linker which is quite different from linux loader located at /lib/ld-linux.so*. This explains why the executables aren't working on Linux